# Can't get granular file .bak or .cmp to restore. "Unable to read cabinet info"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, restore, spweb

I made a granular backup of my site collection into .bak. and now I'm trying to import said file by using

```
Import-SPWeb -identity http:testserver/sites/test -path \\sharedstore\backup.bak
```

I have the site I'm importing to already created at `http:/testserver/sites/test`

When I did this I got this error

> [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Start Time: 5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM.
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Progress: Initializing Import.
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Error: Unable to read cabinet info from \sharedstore\backup.bak
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ExtractFilesFromCabinet(String bstrTempDirectory, String bstrCabFileLocation)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportDataFileManager.Uncompress(SPRequest request)
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] FatalError: Failed to read package file.
>   *** Inner exception:
>   Unable to read cabinet info from \sharedstore\backup.bak
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ExtractFilesFromCabinet(String bstrTempDirectory, String bstrCabFileLocation)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportDataFileManager.Uncompress(SPRequest request)
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Progress: Import did not complete.
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Finish Time: 5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM.
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Duration: 00:00:00
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Finished with 0 warnings.
>   [5/12/2014 8:25:33 AM] Finished with 2 errors.

When I try to use the `-Force` command I get the same error.

I also attempted this with the .cmp file getting the same results as above. The error mention not being able to read cabinet info.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to get the restore to work?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from SharePoint Granular backup(**Perform a site collection backup**) you are getting the backup of site collection( which is Backup-spsite) not the export.that's why you are getting the error when running the import file. Please run the below command( make the changes according to your environment).

```
Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

Comment: quick question if you know. It successfully restored my site, but the site seems to be showing all the icon images, not showing suitebar, or ribbon menu. I checked to make sure all the css files that I had on the other site transferred and they're there any idea? (will post an image on original question)

Comment: looks like either backup is not write or restore not completed sucessfull. did you check the logs, any warning or error during the restore. I would try to take the fresh backup and restore it.

Comment: For whatever reason the is didn't create a log event in the backup folder. I'm going to try it again and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: I ran the restore and it works this time. The restore previous gave me no errors or warning messages, so I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time.